# Is it possible to constrain NMACoreRouter to exclude roads with speed limits above a certain thresholds?

Tags: ios, here-api

Aside from finding all NMARoadElements that match this criteria and applying penalties, that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, Here Mobile SDK doesn't provide a ready made solution to the above ask. You can use PDE API (read in developer site) to find the speed limits and avoid specific links/roads in your code.

Comment: Thank you. As a follow up, I'm having difficulty finding in your documentation how I would find for example, a list of roads matching a certain criteria using the PDE API.

In which place here https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/resources.html would I find what I'm looking for?